# SQL CRUD Showing UPDATE As SQL System Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

So after playing around with SQL 2012, I noticed that `UPDATE`shows as SQL System Functions In Magenta?

Just Wondering as `SELECT`,`DELETE`and `INSERT`  show blue?Surely they would all show as blue as `UPDATE`is not a system function?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update is a function in SQL Server. [UPDATE() (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

If you want the coloring to change you can vote here. [Syntax Highlighting: UPDATE keyword is pink](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/736225/syntax-highlighting-update-keyword-is-pink)